# Elements on the canvas disappear w/ jsfiddle

Tags: node.js, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem using fabric.js in canvas. After resize with scale factor at 5x, clicking in ZoomIn 2 times, the elements on the canvas disappear. Please look: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/Q3TMA/90/

Canvas size (just for example):

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Zoom Scale Factor:

```
var SCALE_FACTOR = 5;
```

Is there any solution?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are also resizing the canvas, so after zooming 2 times, its size is 10000px * 10000px, meaning 100 megapixels, and several hundred megabytes of memory required.

If you keep the canvas size constant (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TMA/91/)), or limit it to a value small enough, zooming works as expected.

To keep the size constant you just have to remove these two lines:

```
canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);
```

Comment: @ptCoder: Exactly, your elements are not gone!  After 2x zoom-in, they're just off-canvas down and to the right. Notice the scrollbars that appear after zooming.  Just scroll down and right and your elements are still there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to large canvas to convert canvas to, for example, 300 or 600 DPI. I need a large canvas size. Is there any solution?

Comment: @markE, What is the browser that you are using? One new example with a canvas with 10000x10000 pixels. You click in ZoomIn 6/7 times and canvas desapear completly. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/Q3TMA/95/

Comment: Yes, so it probably depends on your browser/system what happens with a 10000x10000 canvas. I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I am almost certain that it is possible without creating such a giant canvas...

Comment: IE10 clicking Zoom-in 3X works fine.  The 4th Zoom-in does cause your disappearing (probably exceeding browser capability).  But 3X  gets you from 72 dpi to 72*2*2*2=576 dpi if rescaled.

Comment: Is there another option that I have to create images from canvas at 300/600 DPI? I think that I need to create a large canvas. But I have this problem :(

Comment: Using Node.js is a possible solution?