# Saving canvas with 300dpi (imagemagick) and todataurl / base64

Tags: canvas, imagemagick, html5-canvas, base64, fabricjs

I have a problem saving my canvas. I think that is because my canvas is too large. I have asked for help here:

[Elements on the canvas disappear w/ jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201321/elements-on-the-canvas-disappear-w-jsfiddle)

[canvas.toDataURL() for large canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156402/canvas-todataurl-for-large-canvas)

… but no success.

My problem is the next:

I have a canvas for example with these dimensions: 1123x1965 pixels and I need to resize to 29.7x52 centimeters and put them in 300dpi.

My rational was as follows:

- After the edited template, convert to full size and then save a png image to the actual size in pixels, already multiplied by 300 dpi. Made this calculation:

29.7 centimeters: 29.7*300 = 8910

52 centimeters: 52*300 = 15600

The problem on using this is basically canvas disappear. Please look this: [Elements on the canvas disappear w/ jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201321/elements-on-the-canvas-disappear-w-jsfiddle)

And todataurl function don’t work: [canvas.toDataURL() for large canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156402/canvas-todataurl-for-large-canvas)

- Then use the library imagemagick convert to 300 dpi, like this command: convert test.png -units PixelsPerCentimeter -density 300 test2.png

Anyone can help me?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide what you already have on 2.54 to get pixels based on inches. Although, the more correct term is PPI instead of DPI (as dots on paper behave a little different than pixels on a screen).

```
29.7 cm * 300 PPI / 2.54 = 3508 pixels

52.0 cm * 300 PPI / 2.54 = 6142 pixels
```

(Are you sure about 52 cm is correct ? (A4 short side x2, ie A3, is 42 cm)).

Answer (score 1):

DPI means dots per inch, not dots per centimeter.
300 DPI(dot/in) = 118 dpcm (dot/cm)

The calculations should be:

29.7 centimeters: 29.7*118 = 3504.6

52 centimeters: 52*118 = 6136

I hope this helps solving your problem.
(I cannot give comments, yet. So I put this as an answer)

Comment: Thank You very much. Yes, I think that you are correct. I'm trying implementing it today. Thank You very much.